# How to get a value without characters like "- , + "?

Tags: mysql

This is the normal output:

```
mysql> select module_id from Modules where Module_name = 'STP_XENA';
+-----------+
| module_id |
+-----------+
|         3 |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Can I get answer for the query as only "`3`"

I need something like,

```
mysql> select module_id from Modules where Module_name = 'STP_XENA';

3

mysql>
```

But not from bash or console. Is there any option to do this ?

Comment: The result of the query already *is only `3`*, then what is the problem?

Comment: Give more examples. As stated, your question is very confusing - you already have `3`

Comment: Do you want to get unsign values?

Comment: I think the question is asking how to use the command line mysql client to completely unformatted results (so you can't see column names or where one row/column ends and the next begins)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do it inside MySQL editor, AFAIK. If you execute the script from console, then adding `-B` switch can get you desired result.

```
> mysql -B -u username -p password -e "select module_id from Modules where Module_name = 'STP_XENA';" DBNAME
```

will yield value with column name:

```
module_id
3
```

Also, if you add `--skip-column-names`

```
> mysql -B --skip-column-names -u username -p password -e "select module_id from Modules where Module_name = 'STP_XENA';" DBNAME
```

will yield only value (minus column name):

```
3
```

HTH

EDIT: You may start `mysql` with `--skip-column-names` switch. I am not sure about `-B` though. If you are able to start with `-B`, then great.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the query result in something like a bash script?

If so, you could do with:

```
mysql -u{user} -p{password} -s -N -e "select module_id from Modules where Module_name = 'STP_XENA'" database_name
```

Example:

```
module_id = `mysql -u{user} -p{password} -s -N -e "select module_id from Modules where Module_name = 'STP_XENA'" database_name`
echo $module_id
```

Comment: ＠Karthik So what is the purpose of your requirements?

Comment: I will open a session with mysql, send commands from my script and get o/p. It will be helpful not to format the output everytime.